# Explicit solution of the nonlinear Schrödinger equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Consider the linear Schrödinger equation,
$$ (LS)
\begin{cases}
\partial_{t}u= i\Delta u, t\in \mathbb R,\\
u(x,0)=u_{0}(x),
\end{cases}
$$
$x\in \mathbb R^{n}.$ Taking the Fourier transform with respect to the space variable $x$
in $(LS)$, we obtain,
$$
\begin{cases}
\widehat{\partial_{t}u}(\xi,t)=\partial_{t}\hat{u}(\xi,t)=\widehat{i\Delta}u(\xi,t)=-4\pi^{2}i|\xi|^{2}\hat{u}(\xi,t),\\
\hat{u}(\xi, 0)=\hat{u_{0}}(\xi).
\end{cases}
$$
The solution of this family of ordinary differential equations, with parameter $\xi,$ can be written as, $\hat{u}(\xi,t)= e^{-4\pi^{2}it|\xi|^{2}}\hat{u_{0}}(\xi);$ and then taking inverse Fourier transform, we have,
$$u(x,t)=(e^{-4\pi^{2} it|\xi|^{2}}\hat{u_{0}}(\xi) )^\vee:= e^{it\Delta}u_{0}(x).$$ 
Next, we consider, inhomogeneous problem,
$$ (NLS)
\begin{cases}
\partial_{t}u= i\Delta u +F(x,t), t\in \mathbb R,\\
u(x,0)=u_{0}(x),
\end{cases}
$$
$x\in \mathbb R^{n}, F\in C(\mathbb R:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R)).$

**My Question is**:

> How to show that the solution of $(NLS)$ is given by the formula,
>   $$u(x,t)=e^{it\Delta}u_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}e^{i(t-t')\Delta} F(\cdot,t') dt'.$$

Thanks,

Comment: The solution of an inhomogeneous equation is the general solution of the homogeneous equation and a particular solution of the inhomogeneous. Therefore, you need only show that the integral expression you have solves the inhomogeneous equation, and doing so is fairly straightforward.

Comment: @Ukhrir; thanks; would you please tell me; what is $\partial_{t}(e^{it\triangle}u_{0});$ I don't know how to handle this; as well what is, $\partial_{t}(\int_{0}^{t} e^{i(t-t')\triangle}F(\cdot,t')dt')$ ? ;Thanks,